# Reading JSON object sent from android in PHP?

Tags: php, android, json

i'm trying to create an php script which will data sent from the android to an text file but i'm unable to get the output as there is some error in the php 
here is the php code:-

```
 <?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
    {

        $data=$_POST["OrderSummary"];
        $json=json_decode($data,true);
        file_put_contents("text.txt",$json);

    }?>
```

can any tell me where iam going wrong and how can i corect it ?

Comment: Please post the error message as well

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Barns52 i'm using php 5.6.30

Comment: file_put_contents method is available in PHP5. So that shouldn't be the issue.  The file_put_contents function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure. Try:  
   $result = file_put_contents("text.txt",$json);   
   echo $result;  << And see how many bytes were written

Comment: the problem is the script is unable to read data from the sent data as i have tested the script in postman

Comment: What is the error message? Edit your question and add the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code it will give you more information about what is going on in your script.

Then check the response in you android code.

```
<?php
 // array for JSON response
$response = array();

// Check request method -- for some reason??
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

    // check for required fields
    if (isset($_POST['OrderSummary'])) {

        $data = $_POST['OrderSummary'];
        $json = json_decode($data,true);

        $my_file = 'text.txt';

        $result = file_put_contents($my_file,$json);   
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Number of bytes written = " .$results;
    }
    else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Parameters not correctly formatted";
    }
else{
    $response["success"] = 2;
    $response["message"] = "Somebody is not using the POST request method!";
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Edit:

**I'm not quite sure why you are checking the request method. But I kept it in the PHP script anyway.**

Comment: thanks @Barns52 it works,as iam using an rest api in the android i had to use the post.

Comment: Using post is okay - I use it too, mostly. I just don't think that you have to check the method explicitly.

Comment: the script is now retruning the following data written in the file:-ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray

Comment: Please post all relevant code. This would include the method calling the php script (with information regarding any of the parameters), and the code receiving the response.